# How to setup a group in supervisord?

Tags: python, configuration, supervisord

So I'm setting up supervisord and trying to control several processes and that all works fine, now I want to setup a group so I can start/stop different sets of processes rather than all or nothing. Here's a snippet of my config file.

```
[group:tapjoy]
programs=tapjoy-game1,tapjoy-game2

[program:tapjoy-game1]
command=python tapjoy_pinger.py -g game1
directory=/go/here/first
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

[program:tapjoy-game2]
command=python tapjoy_pinger.py -g game2
directory=/go/here/first
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Now from reading the docs this looks to me like it should work, but calling
`supervisorctl restart tapjoy:`
doesn't do anything.

Am I missing something?

Adding a star doesn't give an error, but doesn't do anything either.

```
supervisorctl restart tapjoy:*
supervisorctl status
tapjoy_game1                     RUNNING    pid 4697, uptime 1 day, 21:56:23
tapjoy_game2                     RUNNING    pid 4698, uptime 1 day, 21:56:23
tapjoy_game3                     RUNNING    pid 4699, uptime 1 day, 21:56:23
tapjoy_game4                     RUNNING    pid 4700, uptime 1 day, 21:56:23
tapjoy_game5                     RUNNING    pid 4701, uptime 1 day, 21:56:23
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to use a `*` wildcard to select all programs in a group:

```
supervisorctl restart tapjoy:*
```

Note: it may that your shell requires you to escape the `*`, usually with `\*`

Comment: @EoghanM: type `supervisorctl help restart`, it is documented there.

Comment: Ah didn't realize there was further documentation after `supervisorctl help`. There's nothing in the online docs.

Comment: @EoghanM: the project has an [open issue](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/250) to document the tool better.

Comment: now you can use the cmd without * like `supervisorctl restart tapjoy:`

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old thread, but I ran into the same problem, and it would've been good to find the answer here. So for future reference, instead of:

```
program=tapjoy-game1,tapjoy-game2
```

You need:

```
programs=tapjoy-game1,tapjoy-game2
```

Docs: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#group-x-section-values

Comment: That was just a typo.  I have corrected it. The problem was actually the need for \\* instead of *.