# Unable to start a Python app using Supervisord

Tags: python, linux, flask, daemon, supervisord

I have a small app that I want to start using supervisord. I've tried the following

- [Installed supervisord and controlled a small script](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)
- Read Introduction, Running Supervisord and Configuration File sections from the [documentation](http://supervisord.org/index.html)
- [Setting up groups in supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923320/how-to-setup-a-group-in-supervisord)

My initial shell script could start and stop celery and Flask as daemons by saving the PID in a text file. Since supervisord would take care of killing it, I got rid of the stop section and non daemonized the script.

After trial and error these are the script and conf duos that I think make sense but they don't work.

## 1

Shell Script

```
#!/bin/bash


if [[ $1 == "gunicorn" ]]
then
    cd /home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
    source env/bin/activate
    python env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:3333 -w 3 gunicornserve:app

elif [[ $1 == "celery" ]]
then
    cd /home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
    source env/bin/activate
    python env/bin/celery -A testrunner worker --concurrency=3 --loglevel=info

else
    echo "Usage:-"
    echo "To start celery:-"
    echo "./hitler.sh celery"
    echo "To start Gunicorn"
    echo "./hitler.sh gunicorn"
fi
```

Conf File

```
[group:hitler]
programs=gunicorn,celery

[program:gunicorn]
command=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/hitler.sh gunicorn
stderr_logfile =/home/abhirath/Desktop/supervisor.err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

[program:celery]
command=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/hitler.sh celery
stderr_logfile=/home/abhirath/Desktop/supervisor.err2.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

---

## 2

Without a shell file

```
[group:hitler]
programs=gunicorn,celery

[program:gunicorn]
command=source env/bin/activate; python env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:3333 -w 2 gunicornserve:app;
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler

[program:celery]
command=source env/bin/activate; python env/bin/celery -A testrunner worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=info;
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
```

stderr_logfile, autostart, autorestart, stopasgroup, killasgroup same as #1

I get a message saying could not find the command **source**. I tried the same command on the terminal in the same directory and it works.

---

## 3

Shell Script

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    
    if [[ $1 == "gunicorn" ]]
    then
        source env/bin/activate
        python env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:3333 -w 3 gunicornserve:app
    
    elif [[ $1 == "celery" ]]
    then
        source env/bin/activate
        python env/bin/celery -A testrunner worker --concurrency=3 --loglevel=info
    
    else
        echo "Usage:-"
        echo "To start celery:-"
        echo "./hitler.sh celery"
        echo "To start Gunicorn"
        echo "./hitler.sh gunicorn"
    fi
```

Conf

```
[group:hitler]
programs=gunicorn,celery

[program:gunicorn]
command=./hitler.sh gunicorn
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler    

[program:celery]
command=./hitler.sh celery
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
```

stderr_logfile, autostart, autorestart, stopasgroup, killasgroup same as #1

---

I also tried using *command=bash -c "command here"* even though I feel it isn't required in the all the above cases. It's mentioned [here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) in the documentation.

I get the following errors and I'm not able to figure out why:-

> Could not spawn
>
> Process Exited too quickly

Comment: In #2 you do not need **source**. You can use: command=/path/to/env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:3333 -w 2 gunicornserve:app

Comment: Note for #3. According to [document](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) "*If it is relative, the supervisord’s environment $PATH will be searched for the executable*", it means that `./hitler.sh` is searched from `$PATH`, not `/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler`

Comment: @ymonad I do not understand that part. I'll ask my colleagues to elaborate on that. Thanks :)

Comment: @MohammadAmin But I need to activate the Python Environment. Don't I? I'll try and get back to you :)

Comment: @Abhirath Mahipal This way you are using the virtualenv, you don't need to activate it.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal it means that you might have to add `environment = PATH="/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"`  if you want to set `command=./hitler.sh`

Comment: @ymonad Thanks. Please answer the question so that I can upvote it and probably accept it in case I don't get a better answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of #2, you don't actually need to activate the virtualenv. You can change it to this:

```
[group:hitler]
programs=gunicorn,celery

[program:gunicorn]
command=/absolute/path/to/env/bin/gunicorn /absolute/path/to/gunicornserve:app -b 0.0.0.0:3333 -w 2
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler

[program:celery]
command=/absolute/path/to/env/bin/celery -A testrunner worker --concurrency=4 --loglevel=info
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
```

Comment: I'll just try it out. Can I wait for sometime even after it works before accepting your answer?

Comment: Sure, but please choose an answer for your question so future visitors can make use of it too. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Absolutely :)

Comment: I get `BACKOFF Exited too quickly`. It gives out could not spawn process and the statements like `could not find module`

Comment: gunicorn and celery. I also tried it with `python /path/to/env/bin/gunicorn ...`. Don't bother yourself just yet, I'll try @ymonad's solution first.

Comment: Just a quick reminder, you should change /path/to/env to your own environment path which would be something like /home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/env

Comment: Please edit your answer.  `/absolute/path/to/env/python /absolute/path/togunicorn arguments here`. This worked for me.

Comment: `command=/path/to/env/bin/python /path/to/env/bin/gunicorn arguments`
`command=path/to/env/bin/python /path/to/env/bin/celery arguments`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129439/discussion-between-mohammad-amin-and-abhirath-mahipal).

Answer (score 0):

@MohammadAmin and @ymonad gave wonderful suggestions which I used in this answer. I found a simpler solution due to the explanation given here -> [Supervising virtualenv django app via supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532486/supervising-virtualenv-django-app-via-supervisor)

Script File

```
#!/bin/bash


if [[ $1 == "gunicorn" ]]
then
  env/bin/python env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:3333 -w 3 gunicornserve:app 

elif [[ $1 == "celery" ]]
then
  export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'
  env/bin/python env/bin/celery -A testrunner worker --concurrency=3 --loglevel=info

else
  echo "Usage:-"
  echo "To start celery:-"
  echo "./hitler.sh celery"
  echo "To start Gunicorn"
  echo "./hitler.sh gunicorn"

fi
```

Since I specify the project directory as an environment path, I needn't specify the absolute path to the Python interpreter in the environment.

Supervisord Conf

```
[group:hitler]
programs=gunicorn,celery

[program:gunicorn]
command=bash -c "./hitler.sh gunicorn" 
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
environment=PATH="/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler"
stderr_logfile=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/Logs/gunicornerr.log
stderr_logfile_backups=1
stdout_logfile=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/Logs/gunicornout.log
stdout_logfile_backups=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
startretries=0

[program:celery]
command=bash -c "./hitler.sh celery"
directory=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler
environment=PATH="/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler"
stderr_logfile=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/Logs/celeryerr.log
stderr_logfile_backups=1
stdout_logfile=/home/abhirath/Desktop/Hitler/Logs/celeryout.log
stdout_logfile_backups=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
startretries=0
```

Comment: I don't think there's much difference between the answers. I like to do it in a Pythonic way.

Comment: @MohammadAmin Actually yeah. I have to type the paths the same number of times regardless. Accepting your answer again.